# scrolling div background css gridlines

Tags: css, gradient, gridlines

I am attempting to create a background grid for a scrolling div where the grid boxes are of a dynamic size.

This works correctly if the background is attached to the body, but the same background remains fixed when attached to a div with overflow:scroll.

```
#content{
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 24%, 
                   rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 25%, 
                   rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 26%, 
                   transparent 27%,
                   transparent 74%,
                   rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 75%, 
                   rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 76%,   
                    transparent 77%, transparent),  
 linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 24%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 25%, 
                  rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 26%, 
                  transparent 27%, 
                  transparent 74%, 
                  rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 75%, 
                  rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 76%, 
                  transparent 77%, transparent);
  height:300px;
  background-size:50px 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOboBp